# How to find Wi-Fi password when it's not saved in the keychain but Mac automatically connects to it

Tags: wifi, password

My Mac laptop automatically connects to a Wi-Fi access point every time I switch it on.

When I go to **Keychain Access** to check the password; I enter the system password as prompted and click **Allow**. But when i check the box **Show Password** the check suddenly disappears and NO PASSWORD is shown. It stays blank.

How do I retrieve the password for the access point?

Answer (score 1):

To exclude a malfunction of Keychain Access.app, you could try the `security` command in Terminal (to be found in /Applications/Utilities/, or search with Spotlight):

```
security find-generic-password -D "AirPort network password" -l "network name" -w
```

Replace "network name" (without the quotes) with the wireless network's actual name.
Hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and a window will pop up and ask for administrator credentials.
  Enter those and click "Allow" to find the password as output in Terminal.

Comment: I have the same problem as the original poster. I was able to use the security command above to show passwords for a different network but not the one I'm interested in. This verifis that the wifi password not being displayed in the Keychain app is specific to that network.